# JavaScript invoke transactions in MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, transactions, marklogic, invoke

I have xml document:

```
<product-inventory>
  <product>
    <name>shoe</name>
    <price>100</price>
    <date>2020-05-31</date>
  </product>
  <product>
   <name>dress</name>
    <price>100</price>
    <date>2020-06-01</date>
  </product>
  <product>
   <name>dress</name>
    <price>200</price>
    <date>2020-06-02</date>
  </product>
</product-inventory>
```

I wrote a program to update the 2nd **price** element, audit such update, finally retrieve the updated document.
The program contains three functions. I still see the old document when the program reaches the final retrieval step.  If I open another window, I do see the updated document.

```
<product-inventory>
  <product>
    <name>shoe</name>
    <price>100</price>
    <date>2020-05-31</date>
  </product>
  <product>
   <name>dress</name>
    <price>700</price>
    <date>2020-06-01</date>
    <audit>
      <modifiedBy>admin</modifiedBy>
      <modifiedDate>2020-06-02T16:12:14.9664853-04:00</modifiedDate>
    </audit>
  </product>
  <product>
   <name>dress</name>
    <price>200</price>
    <date>2020-06-02</date>
  </product>
</product-inventory>
```

The gist of the functions:

```
function  updateDoc() {
**************
   xdmp.nodeReplace(
**************
};

function auditHistory() {
*********************
   xdmp.nodeInsertAfter(
*********************
};

function retrieveDoc() {
  return fn.collection('product')
};

xdmp.invokeFunction(function(){
  declareUpdate();
  updateDoc();
  auditHistory();
}),
retrieveDoc();
```

Can someone explain why I still see the old document when the program reaches `retrieveDoc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to wrap `retrieveDoc()` into another `xdmp.invokeFunction` to see the updated document.

```js
xdmp.invokeFunction(() => {
  return retrieveDoc()
})
```

Comment: Interesting point.  I try to figure out how to put the pieces together so as to minimise excess invoke/eval . That being said, conceivably, they are different txn types.   Thank you!

Comment: The explanation is that the main loop runs in query mode, which causes any reads to occur against the timestamp of the start of the code, causing in-flight changes to never be seen. Also, commit occurs in a delayed fashion, so even in update mode, you would still not see the updates. Wrapping the retrieve in another invoke, creates a new context, running with a later timestamp, causing earlier changes to be seen.

Comment: Without wrapping there would also be risks for dead-locks, for instance when you look for the doc before you update it. The main loop would create a read lock on the doc, and the first invoke would not be able to update until the read lock is released, which only happens when the code finished. Result would be a timeout, and no updates written.